# SheetJS js-xlsx - Add hyperlink formula in cell range

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx

I am unable to decrypt [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)...

The goal is to create a link formula in **each** cell based on another cell.

```js
let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
wb.Props = {
    Title: `export`,
    Subject: "export",
};

let ws_data = [
    [
        "sku",
        "product",
        "picture"
    ]
];

products.map(item => {
    ws_data.push([
        item.sku,
        item.product,
        `=HYPERLINK("/pics/"&${item.sku}&".jpg";"link")`,
    ])
})

wb.SheetNames.push("data");
let ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
wb.Sheets["data"] = ws;
let wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });

saveByteArray([convertBinaryToOctetStream(wbout)], `export.xlsx`);
```

Obviously, this simply puts the `=HYPERLINK("/pics/all/"&sku&".jpg";"link")` text in the cell. How can it be the actual formula?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try mapping the array separately and then use it in the worksheet? I am guessing you want the link in the third column.

```
products.map(item => {
    ws_data.push([
        item.sku,
        item.product,
        'link',
    ])
})

products.foreach(item => {
    ws_links.push("/pics/" + item.sku + ".jpg" )
})
    
wb.SheetNames.push("data");
let ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    ws[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({
      c: 3,
      r: i
    })].l = { Target: ws_links[i] };
}
wb.Sheets["data"] = ws;
let wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });
```